# I want to convert the string 20/01/2017 10:46:19 AM to 2017-01-20 10:46:19 AM in Oracle.

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to convert a string, like

```
20/01/2017 10:46:19 AM
```

to

```
2017-01-20 10:46:19 AM
```

in Oracle. Any idea guys? I tried using to_date and to_timestamp but it didn't work!

Comment: How did you try using those functions, and why didn't it work? (I guess you converted to a date, but not back to a string properly?) Are you actually trying to store the string as a date?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert to date `to_date()` then to char `to_char()`

```
to_char(to date('20/01/2017 10:46:19 AM',
                'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'), 
        'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM')
```

Of course, the bigger concern is why you want to store a date as a string...

Comment: Thank you...I get the string value from a file which I have convert afterwards in Oracle...and I need to format that value to 2017-01-20 10:46:19 AM(date or string) for further processing.

Comment: @Rahul That makes sense, but I would advise that if you are storing to the DB, store it as a date

Comment: Actually, I'm using this code in Oracle data integrator where I have to use the transformed value to generate an XML. Hence I use the intermediate SL code only for transformation and the final result will go to the xml :)